# PHP / PDO with a MySQL Cluster

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, cluster-computing

I have been asked to re-develop an old php web app which currently uses mysql_query functions to access a replicated database (4 slaves, 1 master).

Part of this redevelopment will move some of the database into a mysql-cluster. I usually use PDO to access databases these days and I am trying to find out whether or not PDO will play nicely with a cluster, but I can't find much useful information on the web.

Does anyone have any experience with this? I have never worked with a cluster before ...

Comment: Who's your boss? He deserves a medal!

Comment: I long for the day that a C-level exec mentions refactoring as a high priority

Comment: I've used PDO in a similar set-up (4 databases, each with 1 or two slaves, replication... the works). Your co-workers might find it easier to adopt `mysqli`, because it doesn't force them to adopt the object notation just yet (they will, they have to)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: And the sooner the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this a couple different ways with different levels of success.  The short answer is that your PDO connections should work fine.  The options, as I see them, are as follows:

If you are using replication, then either write a class that handles connections to various servers or use a proxy.  The proxy may be a hardware or a software.  MySQL Proxy (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/mysql-proxy.html) is the software load balancer I used to use and for the most part it did the trick.  It automatically routes traffic between your readers and writers, and handles failover like a champ.  Every now and then we'd write a query that would throw it off and have to tweak things, but that was years ago.  It may be in better shape now.

Another option is to use a standard load balancer and create two connections - one for the writer and the other for the readers.  Your app can decide which connection to use based on the function it's trying to perform.

Finally, you could consider using the max db cluster available from MySQL.  In this setup, the MySQL servers are all readers AND writers.  You only need one connection, but you'll need a load balancer to route all of the traffic.  Max db cluster can be tricky if the indexes become out of sync, so tread lightly if you go with this option.

Clarification: When I refer to connections what I mean is an address and port to connect to MySQL on - not to be confused with concurrent connections running on the same port.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered hiding the cluster behind a hardware or software load balancer (e.g. HAProxy)? This way, the client code doesn't need to deal with the cluster at all, it sees the cluster as just one virtual server.

You still need to distinguish applications that write from those that read.  In our system, we put the slave servers behind the load balancer, and read-only applications use this cluster, while writing applications access the master server directly. We don't try to make this happen automatically; applications that need to update the database simply use a different server hostname and username.

Answer (score -1):

Write a wrapper class for the DB that has your connect and query functions in it...

The query function needs to look at the very first word to detect if it's a SELECT and use the slave DB connection, anything else (INSERT, UPDATE, RENAME, CREATE etc...) needs to go the MASTER server.

The connect() function would look at the array of slaves and pick a random one to use.

You should only connect to the master slave when you need to do an update (Most webpages shouldn't be updating the DB, only reading data... make sure you don't waste time connecting to the MASTER db when you won't use it)

You can also use a static variable in your class to hold your DB connections, that way connections are shared between instances of your DB class (i.e. you only have to open the DB connection once instead of everytime you call '$db = new DB()')

Abstracting the database functions into a class like this also makes it easier to debug or add features

Comment: Don't, it sounds like you're suggesting to write a wrapper class around the existing `mysql_*` queries. That's just hiding the problem

Comment: Not sure how this answer relates to using PDO to access a mysql-cluster ... I thought the master/slave concept was for replication rather than for clusters? (the current system does have a wrapper function around the mysql_query calls that does exactly this)

Comment: I don't know of any special features in PDO for dealing with clusters.. we just have an array of possible servers and we randomly choose one to connect to.   The rest of that was just pointing out that you needed to detect if it's a write command and make sure to send those to the master